# Should I use "in most case", "in most cases", "in the most case", or "in the most cases"?

Tags: grammatical-number, particles

The differences are the particle and the number.

Comment: We say "In most cases".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cases" is plural in the common expression "in most cases."

*In most cases, the flu is not fatal.*

That's a use of "cases" in the medical sense. Here is a more general example:

*In most cases, I eat healthy food.*

The phrase "in most cases" can often be replaced by the word "usually."